# I Want a More Concice Form of Data than an Array

Tags: database, json

This is pretty abstract and isn't truly WordPress related, except that I'm storing this data in a WordPress installation, so I am limited to PHP/MySQL-esque parameters.

Here's what I want to do. I've got a list of Post ID's that I need to store in  specific arrangements, different from their nested order as presented by WordPress. For example:

- ID 101

  - ID 106

    - ID 115
    - ID 116
  - ID 107

    - ID 117
  - ID 108

    - ID 118
    - ID 119
    - ID 120
  - ID 109
- ID 102

  - ID 110

    - ID 121
    - ID 122
  - ID 111

    - ID 123
  - ID 112
- ID 103

  - ID 113
  - ID 114
- ID 104
- ID 105

The idea here is that this is a deep and complex list that could go on recursively forever if needed.

Now I could create a set of nested arrays to house this structure in PHP, but that feels a little sloppy on my end. My question is this: Is there a simpler/cleaner way to store this complex list of nested ID's -- A JSON list, XML list or some other form of data that could be programmatically manipulated as needed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for a complex nested array, I decided that it might be best to keep it to simple two level set of arrays.

```
    $x = array(
            101 => [ (int $parent_id), (bool $completed)  ], 
            102 => [ (int $parent_id), (bool $completed)  ], 
            103 => [ (int $parent_id), (bool $completed)  ], 
            104 => [ (int $parent_id), (bool $completed)  ], 
            ...
        );
```

I realized that I was looking for something simpler like what python offers with its "list" data type. I feel like this is about as simple as I could get with storing an unorder list in PHP/MySQL. Anyone got anything better?

Comment: the `$completed` variable was another reason to go with this design choice, which I didn't mention in the original question.